# .htaccess redirect limit characters to URL

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have got a intranet which is classified as admin / mgmt / rest.  And the URL is `intranet.com`. For the management the intranet is going to be `intranet.com/erw`, which would not exceed 3 characters. I want to use `.htaccess` 3 characters to redirect to a specific URL.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([0-9][a-z]) [NC] <--want a limit of 3 characters only
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://intranet.com/tek
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood

```
# match all intranet 1-3 length domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([0-9a-z]{1-3})$ [NC]
# redirect to url with domain name
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://intranet.com/%1
```